# [Libvirt]Where are the guest log files when qemu:///session is used?

Tags: logging, qemu, libvirt

I am launching my guest in the user mode with (qemu:///session). I can see the xml created in ~/.config/libvirt/qemu. Where is the log file created in this mode? I do not see it in /var/log/libvirt/qemu or in ~/.config/liibvirt/qemu.

Where are the files/logs saved in case of user-mode qemu session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will be in $HOME/.cache/libvirt/qemu/logs